# pandas - reformat dataframe according to type count

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I want to reformat a dataframe `dfA` like this:

```
 id    product
100     type1
100     type1
200     type2
300     type3
300     type4
400     type5
400     type6
```

into a dataframe `dfB` like this:

```
id    cnt_type1  cnt_type2  cnt_type3  cnt_type4  cnt_type5 cnt_type6
100      2           0         0          0          0         0
200      0           0         1          0          0         0
300      0           0         1          1          0         0
400      0           0         0          0          1         1
```

with a count of each type and unique ids.

I'm scratching my head thinking of a way of doing this with `groupby`.

Answer (score 5):

Get dummies and sum level 0 i.e

```
cdf = df.set_index('id')['product'].str.get_dummies().sum(level=0)

     type1  type2  type3  type4  type5  type6
id                                           
100      2      0      0      0      0      0
200      0      1      0      0      0      0
300      0      0      1      1      0      0
400      0      0      0      0      1      1
```

To add the prefix to the column names, use `add_prefix` i.e

```
cdf = cdf.add_prefix('cnt_')
```

Comment: Adding my favor crosstab :-)

Answer (score 3):

Is this what you need ?`crosstab`

```
pd.crosstab(df['id'],df['product']).add_prefix('cnt_')

Out[498]: 
product  cnt_type1  cnt_type2  cnt_type3  cnt_type4  cnt_type5  cnt_type6
id                                                                       
100              2          0          0          0          0          0
200              0          1          0          0          0          0
300              0          0          1          1          0          0
400              0          0          0          0          1          1
```

Comment: this type of question is well repeated but I couldn't find a proper dupe.